Внутренние адреса Docker не работают из вложенных папок
Не работают ссылки на внутренние адреса docker при использовании их из вложенных папок проекта.
Примерная структура папок проекта:
./worker_server
     config.py
     /scraping_and_parsing
         config_2.py

Когда из папки worker_server создается worker, то подключение к БД по сслыке а-ля:
DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql://login:password@host.docker.internal:5432/db' работает нормально (данные берутся из config.py),
Но когда то же самое пытаешься сделать из папки scraping_and_parsing - подключение не устанавливается, а работает только с указанием прямого IP-адреса базы данных,  а-ля:
DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql://login:password@192.168.0.3:5432/db' (данные берутся из config_2.py)
Часть Docker-compose.yml, отвечающая за worker_server выглядит так:
version: '3.8'

networks:
  bridge1:
    external:
      name: internal_bridge

services:

  worker_server:
    build:
      context: worker_server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8004:8000
    command: uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --reload
    volumes:
      - ./worker_server:/usr/src/app
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis_worker_server:6379/0
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis_worker_server:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - redis_worker_server
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    networks:
      bridge1:
        aliases:
          - worker_server
    restart: always

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить проблему.
